# Setup & Execution of Jmeter Distributed Test run from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

i'm looking for some assistance in execution of Jmeter distributed test runs using Jenkins hosted on Windows platform.

I need to know how to

1. Start Jmeter master/slave agents (jmeter-server.bat) from Jenkins machine.
2. how to stop the above process once the test run completes.

Answer (score 0):

A hint: if you don't "stop the above process once the test run completes" you won't have to "start" them.

If you want to control everything from Jenkins you need to install Jenkins agent process on each machine you intend to use as JMeter slave, see [Step by step guide to set up master and agent machines on Windows](https://wiki.jenkins.io/JENKINS/Step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-master-and-agent-machines-on-Windows.html) Jenkins wiki page for more details.

Once done you can create a job which will start JMeter processes using simple "Execute windows batch command" step on the [agent machines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/)

With regards to your point 2 - it's sufficient to set `server.exitaftertest` [JMeter property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) to `true` on slave machines in any convenient way, i.e. by adding [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter-server.bat -Jserver.exitaftertest=true
```

Comment: Hello Dmitri, Thanks much for your comments. This certainly helps me to a great extent and i got answer for how to stop the Jmeter-server.bat.

Comment: But, still im having an question about Jenkins agent setup..  

For example - im having 2-3 projects and each project uses different Masters (Project 1 - server1, Project 2 - Server2, Project 3- Server3) and Jenkins is hosted on different server which is server4. 

Now when i need to setup server1 as node on Jenkins, Remote working directory cant be C: or D: and i need to be specific by defining it as UNC path  like \\Server1\d$\. But when i use this UNC path cmd prompt is not supported by windows by defining it with UNC path to invoke jmeter commands.

Answer (score 0):

For any Distributed Load Run via Jmeter, the pre-requisite is to get the Jmeter-server.bat running to support and enable master-slave communications by Jmeter between Load agents. Initially i had a struggle how to get this executed as first step in Jenkins and then followed execution of Jmeter commands for load test using Remote distributed run. Hence instead of running the pre-requisite condition of running Jmeter-server.bat from jenkins i made it as a Windows service (as load agents are windows machines) which is running all time and whenever Load test starts from Jenkins, the Jmeter-server running in background which will allow distributed run to go.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).